# Homework Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The assignment calls for a user to input 3 radius and 3 height entries which I am to gather in an array and then determine the volume for each. I am stuck on the array. For some reason I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
(CylinderTest.java:19)
```

I get the error at the last (6th, or height of the third entry). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I am having difficulty understanding the logic, is my biggest problem.

Here is the CylinderTest (main)

```
import javax.swing.*;

//Driver class
public class CylinderTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
        {
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
            double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
            volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
        }

        String display = "Radius\tHeight\n";
        for (Cylinder i : volume)
        {
            if (i != null)
                display += i.toString() + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display);
    }
}
```

and here is the Cylinder class

```
public class Cylinder
{
    // variables
    public static final double PI = 3.14159;
    private double radius, height, volume;

    // constructor
    public Cylinder(double radius, double height)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // default constructor
    public Cylinder()
    {this(0, 0);}

    // accessors and mutators (getters and setters)
    public double getRadius()
    {return radius;}

    public void setRadius(double radius)
    {this.radius = radius;}

    public double getHeight()
    {return height;}

    public void setHeight(double height)
    {this.height = height;}

    public double getVolume()
    {return volume;}

    public void setVolume(double volume)
    {this.volume = volume;}

    // Volume method to compute the volume of the cylinder
    public double volume()
    {return PI * radius * radius * height;}

    public String toString()
    {return volume + "\t" + radius + "\t" + height; }

}
```

Comment: Firstable, if you do this: `volume[counter++]` Then you are going to move the counter twice, one in volume[counter++] and another in the for statement `; counter++)`

Comment: For future debugging reference, `CylinderTest.java:19` refers you to the class (`CylinderTest.java`) and line number within that class (`19`) where the error is happening.  What line is #19 exactly?

Comment: It was a nice try for a homework question. I think just what nhgrif suggests was missing. In this case the CylinderTest class is irrelevant since the issue is array related. I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: line 19 is volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height);

Comment: Also, from what I've heard, it's very bad practice to mess with the iterator for a `for loop` anywhere outside of the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array has size 3, determined by this line:

```
Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];
```

Then you loop from 0 to 5 here:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
```

And then you try to access one of those indexes here:

```
volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
```

As the array has length 3, it only has indexes 0, 1 and 2. And yet you try to access indexes higher than two.

As a side note, I suggest you change the statement to `volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);` otherwise you are increasing the for-loop variable `counter` twice in each iteration.

A good practice when looping through indexes in an array is to use the array's length in the condition:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++)
```

This will make sure that it only iterates through the indexes that exist in the array, no matter how big or small it is.

Comment: thank you. I now have an array of 6, and a for loop of three. It seems to be working. And I think a small lightbulb went on in my head as to the logic. thanks!   Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[6];

  for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
  {
   double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
     .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
   double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
     .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
   volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
  }

Comment: @user2802785 Don't forget to change your for-loop condition also as I suggested. `for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++)`

Comment: Here's what I have now:  Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];
  for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++)
  {
   double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
     .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
   double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
     .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
   volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
  }

Comment: how do I signify code in comments? I do CTRL+K in the question, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: Thank you. I have another user protocol question. If I have another question on the same code, but unrelated to the initial question, should I begin another topic?

Comment: @user2802785 Yes, please ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Cylinder` array has only 3 elements.  `Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];`

Your `for loop` is trying to access elements after element 2 within this array.  Those elements do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a 3 size array of Cylinder and you are trying to read the 6 of them.

```
Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3]; // 3 size array

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) // loop 6 times
        {
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
            double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
            volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height); // read 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
        }
```

That should be:

```
Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3]; // 3 size array

        for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++) // loop 6 times
        {
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
            double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
            volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
        }
```

Note the volume.length instead of 6 and the ++ removed in volume[counter++]

Comment: Your `// read 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..` is actually a) writing/setting, not reading. b). Indexes 0, 2, 4 because the counter variable is increased twice in each iteration.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yeah, I meant "trying to"

Comment: Thanks. I've tried everyone's suggestions and all are working. Using volume.length is a great tip!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your array has been declared with a size of three. But, in your for loop, you access at the very least 6 elements of the array. So you will have increase the size of your array to at least 6. And you should change the code:

```
volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
```

To

```
volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked. I was thinking it was a 3 item array with each item having two properties :/

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure with this?

```
    Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3]; 

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
    {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
        double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
        volume[counter++] = new Cylinder(radius, height); 
        //counter will count up to 5 (Array out of Bounds exception for sure..)
        //also: why are you incrementing counter by yourself?
    }
```

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: And actually this will not cause the array out of bounds assuming we have the array of size counter since the counter will increase AFTER returning the last counter value, so if we had 6 elements in the array it would call the array in the position 5, move the counter to 6 and get out of the loop.

Comment: @porfiriopartida In the code in this so-called answer, `volume.length` is still 3.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg: okay. i'm new here, and i can't post comments by now. also i didn't know that this is what a comment should look like. sorry for that :)